# Android Google Maps v2 not shown on certain devices

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I found issue that Google Maps V2 for Android are not shown on certain devices (both release version).

Devices for comparison: Nexus 5 and 1 plus 1.

Any ideas?

*UPD:*

Does it make sense the package name? I have package name: com.severenity - without third part. I have created absolutely new project from scratch using maps template and it worked with name: com.severenity.test. I also have SupportMapFragment inside my another fragment. With MapView on both project maps are not shown. Any ideas?

Comment: Reasons for downvote? I have tried multiple solutions on other similar questions and none helped, that's why that question did appear. Admins?

Comment: I am still trying to resolve it. Couple more mobile devices do not show the map: Lenovo, Xiomi and more. But some do show.

Comment: Having a logcat trace and a screenshots would be helpful inorder to diagnose the issue. Note: I did not downvoted your question ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what is going on with this issue, may be helpful for others:

- I created separate project, which had MainActivity and SupportMapFragment in the layout. It worked on devices, that were not showing the map.
- In my project I had, lets say, CustomFragment, which had in its layout SupportMapFragment:

  ```
  <FrameLayout
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/map" />

  <!-- other views go here -->
  ```

  And it does not work, BUT! I had "hardwareAccelerated='false'" in AndroidManifest, so after I turned it to "hardwareAccelerated='true'" it started to work on other devices. Magic? At least, this is the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you've integrated the Google Maps SDK it should work on all devices that support Google Play Services with the exceptions below:

- Devices that don't have Google Play Service (devices manufactured for the Chinese markets, some custom ROMS, and some jail broken devices)
- Devices that are accessing the internet behind a firewall that is blocking Google (China Firewall is an example)

You need to ensure that you have integrated the SDK correctly:

- Created an API Console Key
- Set the API Key correctly in the Android Manifest
- Have asked for the correct permissions
- Have delegate all life-cycle events to the MapView

Here is the [Getting Started Guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start).

Comment: Sometimes an outdated Google Play Service also causes this issue.

Comment: Thank you for your reply (especially regarding exceptions). I will try one more fix and will let you know the results.

Comment: I have tried on 1 plus 1 again, after I changed MapFragment to MapView, and have delegated all life-cycle events, but map did not show. Console key is created (for debug and release), Manifest has API key and permissions are granted. Am I missing something? it does show on my nexus 5. I am installing right from the IDE. Help, please!

Comment: Can you please post your code on Github or on here.